# How to import shapefile into postgresql using PHP

Tags: php, postgresql, cmd, exec, shapefile

Below command is succesfully uploading the shapefile into postgresql via cmd.

```
shp2pgsql -I -s 4326 E:\SAITEJA_AND_VISHAL\sampleData\dist_bnd.shp  haryana | psql -U postgres -d haryana
```

I am unable to do it through php. Please help me to resolve this.

```
<?php

$command = 'C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin.exe shp2pgsql -I -s 4326 E:\SAITEJA_AND_VISHAL\sampleData\dist_bnd.shp  haryana | psql -U postgres -d haryana'; 
$output = exec($command);
  print_r($output);
?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you run this app with admin permissions?

Comment: @Nikita yes. when i ran the command in cmd it asked the password for the database and succefully done. i am facing trouble to run it through php.

Comment: Ok, how do you try to run the application? From web browser? Try to open cmd with admin rights and run your program via `php application.php` Same result?

Comment: i want to run the application in web browser.

Comment: try to add `runas /user:administrator` before command into your command

Comment: Or try to create the batch file with your command and set execution only from an administrator. And call it from your exec() method in PHP

Comment: i tried it . it does not work. i CMD it asks for password and then it works . in PHP i dont get where can i put password. please help in that . thank you

Comment: Looking at this from the `cmd` perspective, the path to the executable contains a space character. It may need its own quoting. `'"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin.exe"...` Also, I would have expected `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin\shp2pgsql.exe`, but I do not know PostgreSQL or PHP.

Comment: yea okay thank you. i will look onto it.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced exactly the same problem (command works in cmd but nothing when called via PHP). What helped me a lot was to retrieve the error message (by adding: 2>&1'& $output). MY command looked something like:

```
?php
exec("\"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin\shp2pgsql.exe\" -s 28992 -I -W 
latin1 D:\somefolder\someshape.shp someschema.example_shape | psql -U postgres -h localhost -d somedbname 2>&1", $output);
foreach ($output as $key => $value)
{echo $value;}
?>
```

It returned "'psql' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file." My fix was to define the full path of the psql executable in the command like this:

```
<?php
exec("\"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin\shp2pgsql.exe\" -s 28992 -I -W 
latin1 D:\somefolder\someshape.shp someschema.example_shape | \"C:\Program 
Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin\psql.exe\" -U postgres -h localhost -d somedbname");
```